# Как получить компонент, владеющий фокусом?

Tags: gwt, java

Есть ли какой-то аналог метода

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getPermanentFocusOwner()
```

библиотеки AWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А не проще ли пробежаться по всем контролам и проверить на каком установлен фокус?!

```
// this.Controls - контролы на форме =)
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control.Focused)
        // покажем текст который написан на контроле... или типа того )
        MessageBox.Show(control.Text);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться интерфейсом [HasFocusHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/FocusHandler.html). Дальше с помощью [FocusHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/FocusHandler.html) подписываемся на события [FocusEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/FocusEvent.html), которые будем получать при каждой смене фокуса

Comment: то есть вы предлагаете добавить этот handler ко всем компонентам, которые могут получать фокус? вопрос не в том, чтобы отследить состояние конкретной компоненты, а получить текущий сфокусированный компонент